# Unix Get only Difference between 2 files

Tags: unix, diff, difference

Hello i am trying to compare the files inside 2 directories and output all the new lines, but i am getting the new lines.

***My question is how to output each file difference to a separates file not all on the same output. Thank you***

**Here is the Command:**

```
[root@ links]# diff -r directory1/ directory2/
```

**Here is the output :**

```
diff -bur directory1/file1 directory2/file1
--- directory1/file1    2016-11-16 07:10:48.646726219 -0500
+++ directory2/file1    2016-11-16 07:11:02.358639590 -0500
@@ -3,3 +3,8 @@
+6
+7
+8
+9
+10
diff -bur directory1/info1 directory2/info1
--- directory1/info1    2016-11-16 07:04:35.496097219 -0500
+++ directory2/info1    2016-11-16 07:05:19.840813752 -0500
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
+d
+e
+f
+g
+h
```

What i need is each difference on a separate output file like this:

**output 1**

```
diff -bur directory1/file1 directory2/file1
--- directory1/file1    2016-11-16 07:10:48.646726219 -0500
+++ directory2/file1    2016-11-16 07:11:02.358639590 -0500
@@ -3,3 +3,8 @@
+6
+7
+8
+9
+10
```

**output2**

```
diff -bur directory1/info1 directory2/info1
--- directory1/info1    2016-11-16 07:04:35.496097219 -0500
+++ directory2/info1    2016-11-16 07:05:19.840813752 -0500
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
+d
+e
+f
+g
+h
```

Comment: Why don't you do `diff -bur directory1/ directory2/ > output_file`, if you want this output to be written to a file? Your question is unclear to me. How many files are there in each directory? How many output files do you want?

Comment: i did but will output all to the same output, if i have 2 files being compared i need 2 outputs ... each difference on a seperate output file

Comment: your question is not very clear. How do you want your two files look like?

Comment: i just updated the question now is clearer please have a look @Sean83

Comment: No the diff is mart enough to only compare files with the same filename @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: @Johnny Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot do that using diff.

However, you can by alternative tools in Linux. 
For example, **vimdiff** which gives you seperated page that you prefer and  there are other tools like kompare and diffMerge. Please refer to this link. [HERE](http://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/)